# Как деплоить docker-контейнер без простоя?

Tags: docker, развертывание, devops

**Что имеем:**
2 docker-контейнера: app (node.js) и nginx (reverse-proxy)

**Требование:**
Иметь минимальный простой сервиса.
Некоторые запросы могут выполняться долгое время. Важно вернуть ответ на запрос, который пришел до деплоя.

**Суть проблемы:**
При обновлении проекта (docker-compose build && docker-compose up -d) имеем простой 5-10сек. (время запуска node.js в контейнере app).

**Как я себе представляю решение:**

1. Использование Green/Blue паттерна. Не смог найти простого решения (без костылей)
2. Стек Docker Swarm

Подскажите максимально простой подход к деплою с нулевый простоем (при отсутсвии DevOps'a).

**docker-compose.yml**

```
services:

  app:
    build:
      context: .
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env

  nginx:
    build: ./docker/nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - app
    ports:
      - ${APP_PORT}:80
    volumes:
      - ./static:/var/www:cached
```

Answer (score 0):

Сама идея с тем, чтобы *вернуть ответ на запрос, который пришел до начала деплоя* является крайне утопической, так как во время деплоя останавливается процесс, который этот запрос обслуживал, а также уничтожается TCP соединение (и сессия TLS), которые этот запрос обслуживали. Восстановить эту парочку не получится.

Можно изобрести жуткие костыли с реверсивным прокси (решает проблему с соединением и сессией) и насочинять транзакционную модель отправки ответа клиенту, но это будет очень усложнено.

Более технологичный ответ - это *интернет, детка* - запрос всегда может отвалиться просто потому, что данные идут через интернет. Клиенты должны это учитывать и посылать запрос повторно, если с первым не сложилось.